# Responsive and centered iFrame

Tags: html, css, iframe

I want an iFrame to be responsive and horizontally centered on the page, but I also want a max-width of 500px for it. For now I only succeed of making it responsive but not centered.

```
const VideoWrapper = styled.div`
  max-width: 500px;
`;

const IFrameContainer = styled.div`
  position: relative; 
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 88%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
`;
```

I chose 88% because it is the correct format for my video, the responsive works perfectly.

But when I try to add a flex display with justify content center, the iframe will disappear. Same for margin-left/right auto.

```
<VideoWrapper>
   <IFrameContainer>
      <iframe title="player" id="player" scrolling="no"></iframe>
   </IFrameContainer>
 </VideoWrapper>
```

This is React and styled component code.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is probably because your iFrame has a width and height of `100%` and the parent container has a height of `0`. When you add `flex-box` the containers width will additionally shrink to 0 because it only occupies the same space as its content by default, which is 0.

Comment: ...to use `margin: 0 auto` the container you want to center also needs a width that is smaller than the one of its parent container ;)

Comment: Yeah actually all I needed to do was add a width of `100%` and the `margin: 0 auto` both in the container.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use margin:0 auto; with the max-width.